# In App Purchase Content for a Different App

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I currently have an app that is divided into multiple apps.  I'd like to combine them all into a single application with the ability to use In App purchasing to download the parts currently held in multiple apps.  Is there a way that I can allow people who currently own the individual apps to somehow make an In App purchase that unlocks the parts in the single app?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to use a web server holding user accounts and in-app purchases. If you require an offline solution, I will suggest you to use iCloud Keychain, you can mark your apps sharing the same keychain in XCode.

To enable keychain sharing:
-Select the target in XCode
-Go to capabilities
-Enable keychain sharing 
-Add a group with same name for all apps.

After all your apps will be able to reach this shared data.

If you are not familiar with keychain [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) will be a good start. Keychain is not that complicated.

EDIT: woops didn't even notice I'm answering a 3 year old question.